# Bloodskal Barrow won't appear

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I am on the dawnguard quest 'rings of blood magic' i have obtained the ring that quadriples khajit claw attacks and gives +100 health, but Bloodskal Barrow won't appear on my map, i have tried repeatedly activating and deactivating the quest but there is still no marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bloodskal Barrow is on Soltsheim (Dragonborn DLC). You'll have to travel there to see a quest marker.